# Can't inflate ViewPager in Jetpack example app

Tags: android, gradle

I cloned the Sunflower example app (https://github.com/googlesamples/android-sunflower) as a baseline structure to learn against (I'm obviously new). I want to use ViewPager and it gives the following runtime error:

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v4.view.ViewPager" on path: DexPathList[[...
```

I've tried numerous changes to my gradle file to resolve this based on searches, but haven't found anything that works. Here are the current dependencies:

```
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$rootProject.roomVersion"
implementation "android.arch.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$rootProject.navigationVersion"
implementation "android.arch.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$rootProject.navigationVersion"
implementation("android.arch.work:work-runtime-ktx:$rootProject.workVersion") {
    exclude group: 'com.google.guava', module: 'listenablefuture'
}

implementation "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:$rootProject.constraintLayoutVersion"
implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:$rootProject.ktxVersion"
implementation "androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:$rootProject.lifecycleVersion"
implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"
implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$rootProject.roomVersion"
implementation "com.google.android.material:material:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"
implementation "com.google.code.gson:gson:$rootProject.gsonVersion"
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$rootProject.kotlinVersion"
```

Can anyone tell help point out what I'm missing? Thanks.

Comment: use `androidx.viewpager:viewpager:1.0.0`.

Comment: Thank you! I need to read about androidx :(